# Catch rails confirm box action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs

I have the following rails button:

```
<%=
  link_to "Remove Product", product_path(product),
    remote: true,
    method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this product?' }
%>
```

I'm using rails-ujs to show the `confirm()` dialog; is there an easy way catch the confirm answer with javascript?

Comment: Your question is tagged with [tag:ujs]; so I think you're already using UJS, and you get a confirmation, but you want to get the answer if JS, rather than the default confirm from UJS?

Comment: I want the default confirm action but I also want to catch the event and do some other things as well, depending on the answer. Basically I was wondering if it is possible to keep the default functionality and also catch and do something special with a manual way at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `confirm:complete` callback; this is not documented, as far as I can see, I found it by [looking at the source](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L249).

This gets executed right after the `confirm()` call:

```
$(document).on 'confirm:complete', (e, answer) ->
  alert "Your answer was: #{answer}"
  return true # You can still cancel by returning false here
```

Comment: Well I want to catch the event and the "answer" of the user. This one is launching before the confirmation and it is mainly for customizing the behavior and creating your own custom confirmation box. I just want to catch the answer and do something additional with the default behavior.

Comment: @JohnDel How did I forget this...? >_< I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but this one works only when you click "Ok" on confirm, it doesn't work on cancel.

Comment: @JohnDel Hm, it works for me ...I'm using Rails 4.1.8, are you maybe using Rails 3?

Comment: Oh you are right, I haven't put return true before. Now it works!

Answer (score -1):

you can handle onclick event and use this:

```
if (confirm("Say hello?")) {
  alert("hello!");
  ....
} else {
  .....
  alert("another")
}
```

Comment: Yes that's a general code which I can use to handle it by my own, bypassing altogether the default functionality of rails (and without using the data-confirm).